# How could I calculate weight for FICO score?

Tags: python

It is like from our data set at first we have to classify our chosen variable into x1, x2, x3, x4 and x5. Then we need to create a model and need to consider their  weights.
Like:

```py
y = (x1*w1) + (x2*w2) + (x3*w3) + (x4*w4) + (x5*w5)
```

Here my question is how code I do it in Python? any idea? Actually I'm new in Python any help (for code) will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much exactly as you have written it. You could put it inside a function as follows:

```
def fico_score(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,w1,w2,w3,w4,w5):
   return (x1*w1)+(x2*w2)+(x3*w3)+(x4*w4)+(x5*w5)

y = fico_score(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5) # Call the function (here just with random numbers)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it like this

```
x1=2   #giving the random data to all the variable
x2=3
x3=1
x4=5
x5=6
w1=2
w2=3
w3=1
w4=5
w5=6

result=(x1*w1)+(x2*w2)+(x3*w3)+(x4*w4)+(x5*w5)  #appling the formula

print(result)
```

Comment: hope it helped do let me know if any query left